# Limit in two variables with polar coordinates and parameterization

Tags: limits, trigonometry, continuity

i have a problem with this exercise.

Given the function $ \left\{\begin{matrix}
(\frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2})^2 if  (x,y)\neq (0,0)
\\ 
0 if (x,y)=(0,0)\end{matrix}\right. $ test its continuity.

The function is defined for $ {(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:x^4+y^2\neq0} $, so it's a continuos function in its domain and it's worth zero in $ (0,0) $. 
To test the continuinity in point i pass to the polar coordinates.
Now, i'm arrived to proof [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxBbA.jpg) that:

$ \lim_{\rho ->0^+}\frac{\rho^2}{\rho^4+1}=0 $

But, parameterizing with $ \gamma=\left\{\begin{matrix}x=t\\ y=t^2\end{matrix}\right. $  i've proved that $ \lim_{t->0}(\frac{t^2}{2t^4})^2=\frac{1}{4} $.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

From  $$\rho^4\cos^8 \theta + \sin^4 \theta \le  \rho^4 + 1,$$

we can't conclude that

$$\frac1{\rho^4\cos^8 \theta + \sin^4 \theta }\le  \frac1{\rho^4 + 1}$$

$\frac1x$ is a decreasing function over the positive domain.

Also, $(a+b)^2 \ne a^2 + b^2$ in general.

In fact the limit doesn't exist. If you travel along $x=0$, we get $0$ but if we follow the path $y=x^2$, we get $\frac14$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Obviously with restrictions it can be proved that the limit doesn't exist but i was trying to arrive at the same result with polar coordinates. If, like you said, i can't conclude in that way, how can i proceed with the calculations? I'm stuck.

Comment: you can travel along $\theta = \frac{\pi}2$ and $\rho = \tan \theta \sec \theta$.